# I have 2 elements that I want to style with the same <span class>. Is there a way to split or merge those elements with CSS?

Tags: css, youtube, twitch

(First time using StackOverflow, apologies if my formatting is wrong)

As a background: I'm trying to unify live chat from both Twitch and Youtube so they can be both show in the same page at the same time.
Most popular site that does that, StreamLabs, unfortunately doesn't work very well for that, since messages coming from Youtube sometimes get "stuck", which very often make them stop appearing and then they appear all at once.

After checking for alternatives, I came across a site called Botisimo that does that and doesn't have that problem that StreamLabs has, but unlike Labs, I can't manually edit the HTML/CSS/JS of the now unified chat. It shows up in a very simple manner.

[How it shows the messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZE2r.png)

However, as I'm putting that chat as a browser page in the streaming software, I can manually edit the CSS of that page, but nothing else, which shouldn't be a problem.

The problem appeared after I inspected the page to see the names of the divs/spans I had to change in the CSS: **There's 2 spans with the same name**.

You can see in the image that before the username, there's 3 badges. Those 3 badges and the username are both called "name"

The code that shows after each message is sent is:

```
<div class="flex-none message chat" data-platform="twitch" data-name="MOD_LeviathaN" data-message="Testing">
 <span class="name">
  <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/badges/v1/5527c58c-fb7d-422d-b71b-f309dcb85cc1/1" style="margin: 0px 1px;" alt="broadcaster" height="18">
  <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/badges/v1/09606a1c-6cb2-424f-bfb4-3893d1a4dd6f/1" style="margin: 0px 1px; background-color: white;" alt="subscriber" height="18">
  <img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/badges/v1/bbbe0db0-a598-423e-86d0-f9fb98ca1933/1" style="margin: 0px 1px;" alt="premium" height="18">
 </span>
 <span class="name" style="color: rgb(167, 166, 166); font-size: 24px; line-height: 120%;">
  MOD_LeviathaN
  :
 </span>
 <span class="text" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 24px; line-height: 120%;">Testing</span>
</div>
```

So when I style that , it does the same styling on both of them:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7FRe.png)

And I want it to show like this:

[Desired style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb7Zi.png)
This is how it shows on StreamLabs, which have a variable for the badges and for the name itself, and are obviously different. They're both on the same div class, so the styling is applied as intended. On Botisimo however, the messages are also included in the same div class as the other 2, so It gets styled as well, which is not the desired effect.

Is there a way to either split the badges from the username, or put the message outside that div so it doesn't get styled with both of them, **using only CSS since I don't have a way of modifying both the HTML and the JavaScript?**

I also tried to *hide* the badges at least, using the following code:

```
img[alt~="broadcaster"] {
    display: none;
}

img[alt~="subscriber"] {
    display: none;
}

img[alt~="premium"] {
    display: none;
}
```

This did get rid of the badges, but the style still applied to a small part that was still technically there.

[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Wjw.png)

Thanks in advance for all the help. If there's another completely different site that does the same thing (unifies the chat), I'm willing to try it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create similar style to the one you mentioned(Desired style) enclose the both span with class="name" in a div or span and apply the css to that div.
actually when you apply css to class "name" it apply on both seperatly when u will enclose it in a div and apply css to that it will be apply to both as one

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).